# Expand GridView cell to view and download file

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax, gridview

I have one gridview, in this gridview there is one column "File Name" which contains File name.
Requirement: When I click on particular file name, I should be able to see the content of file and able to save or download that file.

All approaches are more than welcome.

```
_________________________________________
|                        |**file name** |
_________________________________________
|                        | a.txt        | <<----Click a.txt    
_________________________________________
|                        | b.txt        |
_________________________________________
```

Regards,
Vivek

Comment: Do you need to display the file in pdf format or just save that file?

Comment: Anything is fine with me. Main thing is I want to view contents of file when I click on file name and there should be an option to save contents of file. File format is not my concern.

Comment: Can you please display the contents of your grid view..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this, open new popup.aspx page with filename as queryparam.
In the new popup page page_load, read the content and write it to the browser

```
<asp:GridView ID="FilterGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="FileName" >
            <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:HyperLink ID="ActionHyperLink" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FileName") %>' NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("FileName","~/FilePopUp.aspx?filename={0}") %>' Target="_blank" />
               <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FileName") %>' NavigateUrl='<%# String.Format("filepopup.aspx?filename={0}", Eval("filename")) %>' onclick="javascript:w= window.open(this.href,'DownloadFile','left=20,top=20,width=500,height=500,toolbar=0,resizable=0');return false;"></asp:HyperLink>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

The pageload of popup

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            if (Request.QueryString["filename"] != null)
            {
                //Get the content from database
                byte[] fileContent = ....;
                Response.Clear();
                string doctype = ...;
                if (doctype == ".doc")
                {
                    Response.ContentType = "application/msword";
                }
                else if (doctype == ".pdf")
                {
                    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                }
                else if (doctype == ".xls")
                {
                    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
                }
                else if (doctype == ".xlsx")
                {
                    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
                }
                Response.BinaryWrite(fileContent);
            }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for providing less information.
File Content is Coming from Database Table.
A Table has one column "File Content". So on the basis of Click Event on a particular file name, I will execute query to fetch file content from DB.

Comment: I added a javascript version, the Hyperlink2 control

Answer (score 0):

Have a link button or button to display the file name. Place a div with runat="server" to show the file content.

Handle the file name button click event. In the event, read the file content and set it as the InnerHTML of the div.

The above is for displaying text/html content.

Comment: Clint ID     Hardware No.  FileName    Serial No.

100               5         abc.xml      1007
105               17        xyz.xml      5017